# How does the Lua Account Demo Syntax works?

Tags: syntax, lua, demo

I'm studying the class demo, you can find here https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo?account.
In Programming in Lua they create a new account with this line:

```
 a = Account:new{balance = 0}  -- (1)
```

it seems the same as a normal function call as this:

```
a = Account:new({balance = 0})  -- (2)
```

I understand how the second call works, but can somebody explain me why the syntax in example 1 works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first form is just synctatic sugar for the second form.

See [section 3.4.10](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.10) of the [reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/).